# Создание SFTP пользователя с ограничением выхода выше домашней директории

Tags: debian, linux

Как создать пользователя с `SFTP` доступом?

Делал так:

```
useradd -d /home/test/data -s /bin/bash -m test
```

Не могу зайти ни через `ssh`, ни через `sftp`

Comment: а что говорит консоль об удалённом входе? (неудачном)а что говорит консоль о локальном входе? (пока нам неизвестном)

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под локальном входе?при попытке через SFTP: Ошибка:Server unexpectedly closed network connectionОшибка:Невозможно подключиться к серверу

Comment: А sshd  то запущен?

Comment: естественно!Через root заходит же!

Comment: Локально войти - значит не удалённо, не через ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useradd -d /home/test/data -s /bin/bash -m test
```

Используя ключ -d, ключ -m не нужен как я понимаю.

Comment: Ура, с 36 попытки, командой useradd -d /home/test6/ -s /bin/bash test6 был достигнут желаемый эффект. Тоесть пользователь создался. Только он может за пределы своей папки ходить. Как это ограничить?

Comment: пробуй вот такой метод:http://bukashk0zzz.org.ua/nix/chrootdirectory-ssh-ohranychenyya-dostupa